# Is there a way to put these bars behind the circles?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I couldn't understand how to put these bars **behind** the circles:

REPL: https://play.tailwindcss.com/peSieAptHf

[image]

I'm trying with `z-index` but it doesn't work!

Is there an alternative way?

```html
<div class="flex w-full p-20">
    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="flex mx-auto w-8 h-8 bg-gray-300 rounded-full"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="flex mx-auto w-8 h-8 bg-blue-300 rounded-full"></div>
            <div class="absolute inset-0 flex items-center -translate-x-2/4">
                <div class="h-0.5 w-full bg-green-500"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="mx-auto w-8 h-8 bg-blue-500 rounded-full"></div>
            <div class="absolute inset-0 flex items-center -translate-x-2/4">
                <div class="h-0.5 w-full bg-gray-700"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="mx-auto w-8 h-8 bg-green-500 rounded-full"></div>
            <div class="absolute inset-0 flex items-center -translate-x-2/4">
                <div class="h-0.5 w-full bg-red-500"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: to trigger a z-index on the round, you need a position. relative is fine , and a z-index value. If you add those 2 classes to your rounds : `relative z-10`  they will stand hover the bars.

Answer (score 4):

z-index can be triggered on the rounds if you reset the static position to relative via classes : `relative z-10` .

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex w-full p-20">
    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="flex mx-auto w-8 h-8 bg-gray-300 rounded-full relative z-10"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="flex mx-auto w-8 h-8 bg-blue-300 rounded-full relative z-10"></div>
            <div class="absolute inset-0 flex items-center -translate-x-2/4">
                <div class="h-0.5 w-full bg-green-500"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="mx-auto w-8 h-8 bg-blue-500 rounded-full relative z-10"></div>
            <div class="absolute inset-0 flex items-center -translate-x-2/4 ">
                <div class="h-0.5 w-full bg-gray-700"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="mx-auto w-8 h-8 bg-green-500 rounded-full relative z-10"></div>
            <div class="absolute inset-0 flex items-center -translate-x-2/4">
                <div class="h-0.5 w-full bg-red-500"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set negative z-index to the bars.

To set negative z-index, check the docs at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/z-index#negative-values

After adding the negative z-index setup, your code should look like this:

```
<div class="flex w-full p-20">
    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="flex mx-auto w-8 h-8 bg-gray-300 rounded-full"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="flex mx-auto w-8 h-8 bg-blue-300 rounded-full"></div>
            <div class="-z-10 absolute inset-0 flex items-center -translate-x-2/4">
                <div class="h-0.5 w-full bg-green-500"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="mx-auto w-8 h-8 bg-blue-500 rounded-full"></div>
            <div class="-z-10 absolute inset-0 flex items-center -translate-x-2/4">
                <div class="h-0.5 w-full bg-gray-700"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="mx-auto w-8 h-8 bg-green-500 rounded-full"></div>
            <div class="-z-10 absolute inset-0 flex items-center -translate-x-2/4">
                <div class="h-0.5 w-full bg-red-500"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code in playground and it doesn't work.

Comment: @FredHors I think you need to add `zIndex: { '-10': '-10' }` to config for this to work as stated in link.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing it with css and it worked out:

```
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.bar {
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```